# Combining types in a function dynamically

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm struggling with how to type this function. I have a function that can take `n` parameters of type `ModelOf<T, A>` and returns type of `ModelOf<T_n1 & T_n2 &T_n3..., A_n1 | A_n2 | A_n3...>` Where `T_n` and `A_n` are the generic parameters for the models passed into the function. Here is what I have so far.

```
export interface ModelOf<T, A extends string> {
  initial: Record.Factory<T>;
  actions: (
    update$: Subject<
      (state: Record<T> & Readonly<T>) => Record<T> & Readonly<T>
    >
  ) => {
    [p in A]: (...P: any) => void;
  };
}

const modelA : ModelOf<ShapeOfModelA, ActionsOfModelA> = ...
const modelB : ModelOf<ShapeOfModelB, ActionsOfModelB> = ...

const combineModels = (...models : ModelOf<any, any>) : ModelOf<any, any> => {...}
const model = combineModels(modelA, modelB); // ModelOf<any, any> is not what I want
```

It works but I lose type safety along the way. Is there a way to accomplish this without using `any`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write the `combineModels` function type like this:

```
declare function combineModels<T extends ModelOf<any, any>[]>(
  ...models: T
): T extends ModelOf<infer I, infer U>[]
  ? ModelOf<UnionToIntersection<I>, U>
  : never;

type UnionToIntersection<T> = (T extends any
  ? (arg: T) => void
  : never) extends (arg: infer I) => void
  ? I
  : never;
```

, which makes use of [generic rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters) to infer the tuple type for the `models` function parameter. All instantiations of `T` and `A`  in `ModelOf<T, A extends string>` are then [conditionally inferred](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) as union types `I` and `U` for the return type. We are done, after having converted `I` (the union of all `T`s) to an intersection type.

Test it given some models:

```
interface ModelOf<T, A extends string> {}
declare const modelA: ModelOf<{ a: number }, "fooAction">;
declare const modelB: ModelOf<{ b: string }, "barAction">;

const model = combineModels(modelA, modelB); 
// ModelOf<{a: number} & {b: string}, "fooAction" | "barAction">
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=110#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQgBNgAbAeXQB4AVAGjgEE5RUkiBnODmKZAcwB8cAN4BfAFAlspTFDzYISHnAC2xMowBcBDRWoi4mHUgCuqgEZo4YhgCJ0ECI2wwESu4IDcU4DLkKSirqJKQAQjqEoZRUhhY6PHxI-Db2FnIubh7eEhIwAJ5geACqSO5INBAAkihoHH5ZSLTCALxwABQ0LCBsnEZI+RJwcAD8HXL8OjQAlHAtwgBuEAhEQ3AmwAtos6zA7FztEzrI6NZVs-NwSytrY1VrG1tQPr7+8nDopkiu5XCKlshgFEyBxaN1elxgfoqJgBgxYflBABtAC6gnaawAdNiQiCphJplNwXs+lCYiczgwKVA4MVkSjbrpotRSuVKjVUFB6j8lFQqoIGHSHnAkJs0C9FMp4LjSHM-hAAaKoRx2jLGAwZWFpl44AB6XVMsgxETGEXmKxQMRwABkoni3F4AlscAcTky5TscAAPi70lB3dkJEA)

Hope, it helps!

**Update:**
You can also write it with a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) instead (maybe even a bit easier):

```
declare function combineModels<T extends ModelOf<any, any>[]>(
  ...models: T
): ModelOf<UnionToIntersection<T[number]["t"]>, T[number]["a"]>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQgBNgAbAeXQB4AVAGjgEE5RUkiBnODmKZAcwB8cAN4AoOHBgAuODQlxMsxmIC+YktlKYoebBCQ84AW2JlGswiQrURcdBAiykAV2MAjNHFUMARA4hGbBgEA19BAG4NYC0dPQMjU2sAIUszGyo7dx1ZHj4kfm8-bKggkLDIsTEYAE8wPABVJFCkGggASRQ0DhjypFphAF44AAoaFhA2TkUkGoUAflGdflkaAEo4QeEANwgEIgVnYG20DdZgdi4R5dlkdC92ja24Xf2FuHbDuCRjtCjo2K6ewuJDBFpwfQeZDAKxkDi0CZTLiwjKYWYMNE1QQAbQAuoIRgoAHQkpJw1ZiNZpayUKhNFptTqoKA9MEGWjY1weNC47G+GC+fEMGictyeKC83yYQWCKr6QzwXQcFykeDDSHuaEojgjMmkRgMPXJNYROBiIA)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I used the lookup types